# Formatting Entire Row with Multiple Rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, text-formatting

I would like to change the formatting (specifically text color) for an entire row based on which selection is chosen from a drop down list in Column C. Example:

If C2 equals 'XX'(one of the selections from the drop down list) then A2:G2 will have pink text, but if C2 equals 'AA' then A2:G2 will have blue text... and so on where BB = red, CC = Orange, DD = Green.... until all 8 selections from the drop down box in Column C are assigned a different color. I can only get it to work for up to two colors. Can anyone help me with this formula? I would like it to apply to up to 30 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the whole range, e.g. A2:G30 and then use this formula in conditional formatting

`=$C2="XX"`

Note the $ at the start - that's essential

Select required font colour > OK

repeat for all other text values (I assume you have Excel 2007 or later)